# Multiply two columns sql

Tags: sql

I've created a view called `marks` containing marks grouped by city

```
+---------+----+
|city     |mark|
|---------|----|
|paris    |-1  |
|london   |-0.2|
|new york |-0.1|
+---------+----+
```

and I have another view `factors` which looks like this:

```
+---------+-------+
|factor1  |factor2|
|---------|-------|
|0.2      |0.5    |
+---------+-------+
```

And I want to multiply each mark in the first table by factor1 in order to get this:

```
+---------+--------+
|city     |new_mark|
|---------|--------|
|paris    |-1*0.2  |
|london   |-0.2*0.2|
|new york |-0.1*0.2|
+---------+--------+
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    city, ((SELECT factor1 FROM factors) * mark * 1.0) AS new_mark
FROM 
    marks
GROUP BY
    1
```

but with no success, I get the following error:

> ERROR: column "marks.mark" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Can I get some help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using `group by` in the first place? You don't do anything with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the subquery in the `from` clause and no `group by` is needed:

```
SELECT m.city, (f.factor1 * m.mark * 1.0) as new_mark
FROM marks m CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT factor1 FROM factors) f;
```

Comment: Why use a subquery? Why not just use `FROM marks m CROSS JOIN factors f`?